# Gevent - Make blocking calls non-blocking

Tags: python, asynchronous-programming

I have the blocking code shown below.

Is calling `monkey.patch_all()` enough/optimal to make it non-blocking?

Does Gevent handle iterations like these?

```
# front page
def front_page():
    database = db.posts.find() # find all items in posts collection

    return render_template(
                           'index.html', 
                           database=database
                          )


# single post
def single_post(slug):
    post = [v for k,v 
                in db.posts.find_one(
                                     {'slug': slug}
                                    ).iteritems()
           ] # iterate over found items and store it as post

    return render_template(
                           'post.html', 
                           title=post[3], 
                           body=post[0], 
                           slug=post[2]
                          ) # extract the title, slug and body
```

Comment: Did you check this question with google first? Did you check the documentation for gevent first?

Comment: @Zeroth Yes, but someone says that Monkey-patching does all for you, the other says that it's better to replace the code with its async counterpart because patching is evil. I don't know what advice to follow actually. I would feel better if I knew how to replace those calls with their async alternative effectively though..

Comment: Do you know what the monkey patching is doing? Have you looked up how to use the async alternatives yet?

Comment: @Zeroth It should replace every blocking call with its non-blocking counterpart?

Comment: So, is this okay:

Comment: def front_page():
    db.posts.find()
    gevent.sleep(0)
    
    
    
def iterate():
    for k,v in db.posts.find_one({k: v}).iteritems()
    
gevent.joinall([gevent.spawn(front_page), gevent.spawn(iterate)])

Comment: I mean, there, the comment above ^?

Comment: As I see there seem to be no async alternative but merely async "procedures" as I outlined (and I'm sure in a wrong way) in my example ;)

Comment: I don't know the library. You're asking questions about a very specific, little-used library. Are you sure gevent doesn't have its own mailing list where you can ask this?

Comment: @Zeroth Is it? It looks like the big hype after Node.js and Socket.io..at least it looks better because you don't have to use async methods but procedures. Oh well, it seems that there is, unfortunately it's hosted on Google groups, which ultimately loads horribly (at least for me) :/ Anyway I'll try to post there asap.

Comment: rtfm - This is answered in the gevent docs if you take the time to read through.  They also tell you specifically what `monkey.patch_all()` does, which would also tell you if that will work for you.